# Sort the array of String based on group of consatnt string count

Tags: java

I have a huge group of keys like more than 10L like the below in csv file

ABA,100

ABC,200

ABCs,50

ABM,65

ABMs,86

ABS,86

AC,54

ACLU,123

ACT,56

ACTH,154

AD,644

ADC,76

ADD,10.

Do I need to create the user define an object for the above key pairs? Will it create any memoery problem for creating more than 10L user define object?

My input String looks like  [ABS,AC,ACLU,ABC]

I want the output AC,ABS,ACLU,ABC based on the count.

How to achieve it in easier way of Java 1.8.

Thanks.

Comment: Not clear exactly what you need

Comment: How much is 10L?

Comment: 10lakhs key pair

Comment: My input String is any key of in the csv file. 
Sample input format [ABS,AC,ACLU,ABC].

Based on csv count the above keys are needs to be sorted

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: *"Will it create any memoery problem for creating more than 10L user define object?"* If you have enough memory, it won't be a problem.

Comment: *"How to achieve it in easier way"* Easier than what? You haven;t shown what you've done, so yoo might already have the most optimal way. How would we know if there's an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

You could add each line of your csv to a `List<String> myList`

Then, you will have to create a custom Comparator in order to sort your list based on the value, so something like the following,

```
private void customSorting(List<String> myList) {

    Collections.sort(myList, (String s1, String s2) -> {

          String valuePart1 = s1.split(",")[1];
          String valuePart2 = s2.split(",")[1];

          return Integer.valueOf(valuePart1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(valuePart2));
    });
}
```

Finally, just call your method like `customSorting(myList);` in any place of your code you need it

Of course, you have to modify the sorted list as well to keep only the first part (before comma) for each String value but that's easy.

An **alternative** could also be to create a class like the following,

```
public class MyClass {

     private String key;
     private String value;

     // All the getters, setters, constructors, etc
}
```

, and then read each line of your csv, create an equivalent MyClass POJO and add it to a `List<MyClass> myList`.

You have to write your own custom Comparator again for `List<MyClass>` in a similar way like I did for the `List<String>`,

```
private void customSorting(List<MyClass> myList) {

      Collections.sort(myList, (MyClass a, MyClass b) -> {

           return Integer.valueOf(a.getValue()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(b.getValue()));
      });
}
```

Finally, create a new list from the sorted one by keeping only the keys

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question, the file contains only the strings and the numbers has to be calculated (counting occurrences of each string) in code before the sorting.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson if it is like that, apologies! If he/she confirms I misunderstood, I will of course delete the reply. Thanks for noticing ;)